# iTunes Connect, Invalid Binary, does Apple changed something?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am developed app with Adobe AIR and trying to update application on App Store, successfully uploaded with Application Loader and after submit for review, refreshed page, it says Invalid Binary.
does Apple changed something?

no mail from apple regarding this error

[image]

Comment: Which AIR SDK version are you using ?

Comment: Adobe AIR 25.0.0.143

Answer (score 0):

In my case, issue was related to distriq Application and Core ANE updated them and application submitted for review successfully.

problem was:

> Unsupported operation - Apps are not allowed to listen to device lock
>   notifications.